# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' in C# Yellowbook textbook

Tags: c#

I am following an example in C# Programming Yellow Book by Rob Miles. I copied and pasted this example from the e-book.

- Here is the error:

  ```
      width = double.Parse(widthString); <- this gives the error of: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' <- Why???
  ```
- Full code:

  ```
      double width, height, woodLength, glassArea; string widthString, heightString;

      widthString = Console.ReadLine(); 
      width = double.Parse(widthString); <- this gives the error of: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' <- Why??? 

      heightString = Console.ReadLine(); 
      height = double.Parse(heightString);

      woodLength = 2 * (width + height) * 3.25;

      glassArea = 2 * (width * height);

      Console.WriteLine("The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet"); 
      Console.WriteLine("The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres");

      Console.ReadLine();
  }
  ```

Comment: widthString is supplied by you through Console.ReadLine(). What did you type in? Did you type a valid number?

Comment: Add a watch (or breakpoint) to `widthString` and check if it is a double.

Answer (score 0):

The code reads a string from the console. The string is expected to be a valid double (i.e. 1.2, 4.3, etc) but you seem to be entering something that is not a valid double.

I'd recommend adding some prompts to instruct the user what they're expected to enter. For example:

```cs
    double width, height, woodLength, glassArea; string widthString, heightString;

    Console.Write("Enter the width (as a decimal number): "); // <- Add this
    widthString = Console.ReadLine(); 
    width = double.Parse(widthString); <- this gives the error of: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' <- Why??? 

    Console.Write("Enter the height (as a decimal number): "); // <- And this
    heightString = Console.ReadLine(); 
    height = double.Parse(heightString);

    woodLength = 2 * (width + height) * 3.25;

    glassArea = 2 * (width * height);

    Console.WriteLine("The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet"); 
    Console.WriteLine("The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Cheers, Ian

Comment: This doesn't really "fix" anything though... Users will still find ways to screw this up. Probably better to do a `TryParse` and handle invalid values accordingly.

Comment: The op specifically asked "why" it was causing an error and not how to "fix" the issue he was experiencing. I explained why rather than "fixing" his code as I believed this was the better way for a (seemingly) new developer to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If your input string is empty or non numeric(or too large for the scope of a double var)
if will throw that error. In these situations I prefer to use TryParse.

```
double width, height, woodLength, glassArea; string widthString, heightString;

widthString = Console.ReadLine();
heightString = Console.ReadLine();

double.TryParse(widthString, out width);
double.TryParse(heightString, out height);

woodLength = 2 * (width + height) * 3.25;

glassArea = 2 * (width * height);

Console.WriteLine("The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet");
Console.WriteLine("The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres");

Console.ReadLine();
```

this will output an updated value for height / width if the input is able to be parsed.. If not it will default to whatever it was set to before the parsing attempt.

As mentioned in the comments below (thanks for the feedback) you would also want to validate the input. You could do that in many ways. Below is an example on how to do so:

```
        double width, height, woodLength, glassArea; string widthString, heightString;

        width = GetValidDblInput("Please enter the width:");
        height = GetValidDblInput("Please enter the height:");
        woodLength = 2 * (width + height) * 3.25;

        glassArea = 2 * (width * height);

        Console.WriteLine("The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet");
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static double GetValidDblInput(string inputRequest)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        double val = 0;
        while(!IsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inputRequest);
            if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val))
            {
                IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a valid value (e.g. 1, 3.25, 400)");
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't checking the result of the parse... if the input is bad, now you just have crap output and don't even know it. For example, if I enter "4.5" for width and "abc" for height, `woodLength` will be 29.25.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I 100% agree. This can be improved upon. But the TryParse should get him going in the right direction.

Comment: Indeed it will get OP going in the right direction, but an example with not handling invalid parses is (arguably) more dangerous, because now you still have bad input, but the fallout of it is totally hidden because the program chugs along thinking everything is fine when it reality the state is invalid and you've possibly corrupted important data.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I went ahead and provided an example for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the correct decimal separator when entering the value on the console. If you don't specify a specific format when using parsing methods, the framework usually falls back to the regional format of the operation system the program is running on.

If you want to use a specific format, you can do so by using one of the following overloads:

- `Parse(String, NumberStyles)`
- `Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`
- `Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`

Check out the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Parse_System_String_).

Comment: How do you know for certain that it's the decimal separator? It seems like a very likely cause, but you get the same error with totally invalid input (`double.Parse("a");`).

Comment: I've seen posts on here defy basic common sense in so many ways I hardly trust anything anymore unless it's clearly spelled out.